# Integral of this weird function $ \int \frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I put this equation into Symbolab and it produced me a very complex result
Basically this is the result but I believe there is a simpler way to solve this question

$$
\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\left(2\arctan \left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\sin \left(2\arctan \left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)\right)+C
$$

This was my question
$$
\int \frac{1}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2}dx
$$

Comment: What is this simpler way you think exists? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried substituting different trigonometric functions such as tan, 1/tan etc. None of them resulted in anything useful. I was thinking about a smart decision with substitution that will lead us to a simpler form of answer still equal to the original once such example: cos(2x)^2 i dont know now but something more readable because this is a book question the other answers were simple answers.

Comment: A trig substitution seems like a solid idea, but you'll need to massage the equation to get it into a helpful form before you do. In particular, if we could turn the denominator into something of the form $u^2+a^2$, the substitution $u=a\tan(\theta)$ would be apt. Can you think of a $u$-substution that enables you to do this?

Comment: I cannot, I feel a little disconnected from math since last time I touched trig was years back. Can you see anything? Maybe I can work from there?

Comment: Consider writing the denominator as $\left((x+\tfrac 12)^2+(\tfrac{\sqrt 3}2)^2\right)^2$ and substituting $u=x+\tfrac 12$. What happens?

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $y=x+\frac12$\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx\\
=& \int \frac{1}{(y^2+\frac34)^2}dy
= \int \frac{2}{3y}\ d\bigg( \frac{y^2}{y^2 +\frac34}\bigg)
\overset{ibp}=\frac{2y}{3(y^2+\frac34)}+\frac23\int \frac1{y^2+\frac34}dy\\
=&\ \frac{8y}{3(4y^2+3)}+ \frac4{3\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}\frac{2y}{\sqrt3}+C
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain what did you do after substituting y, how did you fill dy into that d(....)

Comment: @KayraUckilinc $d\left( \frac{y^2}{y^2 +\frac34}\right)$ means $\left( \frac{y^2}{y^2 +\frac34}\right)’dx$, for the purpose of integration by parts

Answer (score 1):

Under $x+\frac12=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\tan\theta$ or $\theta=\arctan\bigg(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}\bigg)$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int \frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx\\
&=& \int \frac{1}{((x+\frac12)^2+\frac34)^2}dy\\
&=& \frac{8\sqrt3}{9}\int\frac{1}{\sec^4\theta}\sec^2\theta d\theta\\
&=& \frac{8\sqrt3}{9}\int\cos^2\theta d\theta\\
&=& \frac{4\sqrt3}{9}\int(1+\cos(2\theta)) d\theta\\
&=& \frac{2\sqrt3}{9}\bigg[2\theta+\sin(2\theta)\bigg]+C.
\end{eqnarray}
Using
$$ \sin(2x)=\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x} $$
one has
$$ \sin(2\theta) = \frac{2x+1}{2\sqrt3}\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$$
and hence
$$ \int \frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}dx=\frac{2\sqrt3}{9}\bigg[2\arctan\bigg(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3}\bigg)+\frac{2x+1}{2\sqrt3}\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\bigg]+C. $$

Comment: There is no simpler way to do this than a trig substitution.  You can further simplify the answer using $$\sin(2\arctan(y)) = \frac{2y}{1+y^2}$$  But the other term is definitely not a rational function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed.